# Android custom listener, order of operations issue

Tags: android, asynchronous, callback, google-maps-android-api-2, fragmentmanager

I am attempting to add a callback from an android MapFragment.

My original code looked something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        //Put the map fragment into the main window
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
        MapFragment sf = (MapFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = sf.getMap();
    }
```

Unfortunately though, there is a delay between the actual call to inject the fragment into the placeholder and the ability for the fragment manager to actually be able to get the GoogleMap because it is asynchronous and may not be finished being instantiated before the call to getMap()

So I decided I wanted to add a callback into the Fragment, on its onActivityCreated() method that will callback to this activity, and do what I need to do with the map then, since by then the Map Should be created and I can call getMap without a problem.

So I created an interface:

```
public interface MapCreatedListener {
 public void onGoogleMapCreation();
}
```

And I extended MapFragment:

```
public class MyMapFragment extends MapFragment {

MapCreatedListener mListener;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
mListener.onGoogleMapCreation();
}

/**
 * @return the listener
 */
public MapCreatedListener getListener() {
    return mListener;
}
/**
 * @param listener the listener to set
 */
public void setListener(MapCreatedListener listener) {
   mListener = listener;
}
```

And I made sure my original activity implements the interface:

```
  public myClass extends Activity implements MapCreatedListener{

  ...

   @Override
   public void onGoogleMapCreation() {
       System.out.println("CALLBACK HAPPENED");
      initializeMap();

   }

   ....

   }
```

So now all the framework is in place to where I should now just need to register my original activity as a listener, by calling

```
            setListener(this);

 from my activity on the mapFragment.... So.. I change my activity code to look like this:

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        //Put the map fragment into the main window
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
        MyMapFragment sf = (MyMapFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        sf.setListener(this);
    }
```

but The findFragmentById always returns null for the same reason... So, how the heck to I link this all up?  I need to get the googlemap but only after its fully created, but that won't happen until after the fragment is created, any my injection of the fragment, and FragmentManager is asynchronous as well... So how the heck do I like this all up, so that my activity will not try to get the GoogleMap before all of this other stuff is finished with its asynchronous stuff?

There has to be a way... I am just not seeing it at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your fragment's onAttach method write this

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
super.onAttach(activity);
try{
mListener = (YourListenerType) activity;

}catch(ClassCastException e){
throw new RuntimeException("Activity must implement my listener");

}


}
```

have the given activity implement the given listener

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be just what I needed and was not finding.